# Store the last edited name of user after edited

Tags: python, django

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to store the last edited name of the user after edited the name. I mean, I want to store previous name after edited the new name.

BUT when i try to access the `name` then it shows the updated name. I also tried by saving previous name while editing but it didn't work for me.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
```

**I also tried** [Tracking Who Made the Last Changes to a Model](https://django-audit-log.readthedocs.io/en/latest/change_tracking.html) BUT i don't know how it works.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with this "last edited name" data? Do you just want a package that will store the complete history of a model instance?

Comment: Yes , That would be much better . I want to save the name which was before edited.

Comment: What do you want the previous name for? How are you hoping to use it?

Comment: If a user want to download profile data then i want to  make the list of names that he/she changed . Do you have any idea how can i do it ?

Comment: @IainShelvington, What happened , Speaking stopped ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom solution by creating a new Model which you are going to use to save the changes whenever a change is occurring.

For example, you can overwrite the `save` method of your model and there you can save the previous state of the `name` field into your newly created `AccountLog`(assuming it is an account) model. The fields there should connect to the model so you can back reference the log from the `Account` model.

This is exactly what `django-auditlog` does but in a more sophisticated way.

https://django-audit-log.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_history.html

As you can see from the querying, you can see all the changes that has occurred by simply adding a `audit_log = AuditLog()` entry in your model.

```
In [2]: Product.audit_log.all()
Out[2]: [<ProductAuditLogEntry: Product: My widget changed at 2011-02-25 06:04:29.292363>,
        <ProductAuditLogEntry: Product: My widget changed at 2011-02-25 06:04:24.898991>,
        <ProductAuditLogEntry: Product: My Gadget super changed at 2011-02-25 06:04:15.448934>,
        <ProductAuditLogEntry: Product: My Gadget changed at 2011-02-25 06:04:06.566589>,
        <ProductAuditLogEntry: Product: My Gadget created at 2011-02-25 06:03:57.751222>,
        <ProductAuditLogEntry: Product: My widget created at 2011-02-25 06:03:42.027220>]
```

Beware that you'll probably want `Tracking full model history` instead of `Tracking Users that Created/Modified a Model` because it follows all of the changes.

Comment: You mean i have to make another model for it, BUT how will django knows which field to save previous data ? I mean do i need to save `full_name` instance same in another `model` ? ( Also updated my question )

Comment: Yes you do need to create another model just for keeping a log of your current model. You will specify which fields are being saved in the `save` method. Basically in the `save` method of your current model you will create the log model (which will have the same fields of your current model) and assign the old values to the log model and then proceed with the saving of the new values in your current model.

Comment: Thanks for Your Help. I will definitely try this. Really Helpful